# Can I attack nothing?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, actions

Combat Expertise can only be triggered via an attack (either standard action or full-round action).

> When you use the attack action or the full attack action in melee, you can take a penalty of as much as -5 on your attack roll and add the same number (+5 or less) as a dodge bonus to your Armor Class.

So since this grants me a better bonus than total defense action, can I trigger it by attacking nothing (e.g. just swinging my blade in the air)? Or do I have to find something to attack?

Since swinging my blade in the air is essentially the same as when I try to attack an invisible creature, it seems to be convincing to claim that "I attack that block defensively, pretending there's an invisible creature at that position". So this character gains +7 (+2 fighting defensively +5 combat expertise) dodge AC until his next round, +3 better than total defense, given that for some reasons this guy cannot retreat and has to stay there until somebody help him out.